# PC rebooting when trying to print

Tags: printer

I have a client with a windows 7 machine. The issue is intermittent, but when she tries to print the PC will shut it's self down and then power back on.

I have uninstalled and re installed the printer, that did not resolve the issue.

If anyone can give me an idea of where to look or something to try I would really appreciate it.

Comment: have you looked in the event log for anything that precipitates the  reboot?

Comment: Which printer and driver? Is the driver for Win7? When "uninstalling" did you just delete the printer (which leaves the driver installed) or also go to Print Server Properties and remove the printer from the Drivers list?